# Setting The Path of an db mdf file in local folder

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, path, mdf

How come The path I inserted in my Database Context is not working? Here's the code for my path

```
private string dbPath = @"TEST.MDF"
DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);
```

But when I run a query this gives me an error

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file TEST.MDF failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, 
>       or it is located on UNC share.

And This is how My Folder looks like this

[image]

The mdf file is in the same location of my cs source code but the thing is they are not reading the path correctly.

my idea for this is that when I transfer to a diffrent pc I don't have to set up the paths again and again. are there any fix for this?

Comment: It's in the same location as your `*.cs` file - but your **executable** is **not** in this directory! When you build&run, your executable is most likely built in `bin\debug` - and in that directory, there's no `test.mdf` file.......

Comment: soo I have to use? the /../../Test.MDF?

Comment: No - you should **attach** your MDF file to the SQL Server instance on your computer, give it a **logical name** and connect to it using that logical name instead of fiddilng around with the .MDF file and its location .....

Comment: but what if I am going to a different computer? then working on it there? and I am trying to give considerations if I am going to install this application somewhere

Comment: If that computer is on the same network - just connect to your SQL Server. If it's a separate network/computer, install SQL Server Express, attach the MDF, and you're good to go

Comment: But my problem here is that, everyday I always switch to different computers, in school, at my house, friends house, I can't install SQL Server Express in my school, only my house.

Comment: Then you should be using something like [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx) which is a simple, single-file database - no installation necessary ever....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
private string dbPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\TEST.MDF";
```

But your Test.mdf isn't in the correct directory. Move it into `\bin\Debug` for this code to work.

Comment: What does Application.StartUpPath do?

Comment: It returns the folder location of your executable. So say your .EXE is in "C:\Programming\Projects\C#\testProject1\bin\Debug". That's the path it returns. And the reason we have to add "\\Test.mdf" is to add the filename to that path, so that the full path looks like:

C:\Programming\Projects\C#\testProject1\bin\Debug\Test.mdf

Answer (score 0):

Better you add your .mdf file in your project.. Add Existing Item=>Choose .mdf file from folder. After adding .mdf file in project, in Web.config or App.Config file connection string will be generate automatically and you can use that connection string to boot your store. Now as you build your project new .mdf file get copy into /bin/dubug folder and you dont need to write single line of code to connect your .mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string :

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="+ AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Substring(0, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.Length - 10)+"sampleDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Because `bin\Debug\` string length = 10, this is why we subtract 10; and now you can get the solution path address and can connect the MDF database.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me in C# with Visual Studio 2017 when I use `|DataDirectory|`.

You need to change your MDF database to the following:

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\students.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```